# Is there a way to auto populate the Alternative text using the image file's Alternative text?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, media

We have an Article content type that has an image field, `field_image`. On upload of a new image, the Name and Alternative text is provided.

When we attempt to add the image to the Article node, we have to enter the Alternative text again even though it was provided on uploaded.

Is there a way to auto populate the Alternative text on the Article node using the image file's Alternative text?

Modules used:

1. [Media entity 8.x-1.7](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity)
2. [Media Entity Image 8.x-1.3](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add Image field (`field_image`) to Article content type.
2. Create a new Article node.
3. Click on "Select an Image" for `field_image` and upload a new image (popup shows up allow you to choose from library or upload).
4. Provide Alternative Text and any other fields to save the image.
5. After saving, the popup disappears and you will notice the Alternative text is still blank

On upload
[image: on upload]

After saving image
[image: after saving]

Comment: That's actually something for drupal.org, a feature request if not even a bug,

Comment: I think we're missing some steps in `Steps to reproduce:` section. Default image field widget only allows uploading a new file, not selecting existing one from the library. Are you using some contrib modules, and if yes - which ones?

Comment: @zaporylie updated question to include modules used.